# Passing parameters to a class function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, javascript-objects

This is a weird one - I'm debugging some JavaScript code in Chrome and I've found that when I'm passing parameters to a class function they're not actually getting passed? 
The weird thing is, sometimes this code works - other times it doesn't.

Here's what I've got (I've trimmed down the code a bit and removed what I think is unnecessary)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var agentID = 'abcd-1234';
        var isCurrent = 'true';
        var colourUtilities = new ColorUtilities();
        var palette = colourUtilities.GeneratePalette(["#2c2656","#362d68","#3f3579","#483d8b","#51459d","#5a4dae","#6a5db8"]);

        GetData();

        function GetData() {
            var url = 'WebRequest.ashx?agentID=' + agentID + "&isCurrent=" + isCurrent;

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    BuildCharts(data);
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, status, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }

        function BuildCharts(data) {
            BuildSummaryBubbleChart(data);
        }

        function BuildSummaryBubbleChart(data) {
            var statusDistributionLabels = [];
            var statusDistributionCounts = [];

            for (var status in data) {
                statusDistributionLabels.push(status);
                statusDistributionCounts.push(data[status])
            }
            var chartBuilder = new ChartBuilder(palette, palette[0]);
            var canvasName = "cVacateDistribution";
            chartBuilder.BuildBubbleLineChart(canvasName, statusDistributionLabels, statusDistributionCounts, "No data available.");
        }
});
```

This part all works correctly - as you can see when I'm debugging in chrome, everything has a value when I call `chartBuilder.BuildBubbleLineChart`:
[image: Debugging in Chrome]
- as you can see, chartBuilder has a value, the canvasName variable has a value and is being passed correctly, the arrays have values.

And yet - continuing to debug, when we jump into the BuildBubbleLineChart function, the values are all undefined: 
[image: Continuing to debug]

I can't for the life of my figure out what's wrong. 
This is the code for the ChartBuilder class (cut down):

```
function ChartBuilder(palette, mainColor) {
var thisBuilder = {};
var charts = [];

//Builds a horizontal chart of circles separated by lines with labels
thisBuilder.BuildBubbleLineChart = function ({
    canvasID,
    labels,
    data,
    noDataMessage = 'No data',
    symbols = null } = {}) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasID);

    if (canvas == undefined) {
        console.log('Error: (BuildBubbleLineChart) Your canvas could not be found');
        return;
    }

    thisBuilder.ClearChart(canvasID);

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
    var canvasHeight = canvas.height;

    if (NoData(data)) {
        canvas.width = 200;
        FillNoDataText(ctx, noDataMessage, 100, canvasHeight / 2);
        PushCustomChart(canvasID);
        return;
    }

    //etc - goes on to build the chart
}
```

There's a tonne of other functions within the ChartBuilder class but none are called/used at any point.

My problem is that when I call the `BuildBubbleLineChart` function and pass it values, it obviously gets to the function and has no values, so it logs the error `Error: (BuildBubbleLineChart) Your canvas could not be found` and returns.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's either you're using the brackets incorrectly in the `thisBuilder.BuildBubbleLineChart`, so you have to fix them, or you're calling it incorrectly because you cannot pass it parameters like mentioned in the previous comment. Is it you who wrote this function?

Comment: I wrote the call but not the function in ChartBuilder. But that's the weird thing - if it expects an object instead of parameters, why does it sometimes work?

Comment: Things don’t just “sometimes” work in JavaScript. Either they work, or they don’t. Can you show an example where everything works as expected?

Comment: You're right, it used to work until someone updated the ChartBuilder function without telling anyone >:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look closely at the parameters:

```
thisBuilder.BuildBubbleLineChart = function({
    canvasID,
    labels,
    data,
    noDataMessage = "No data",
    symbols = null
  } = {}){
```

…

```
}
```

These are [destructured parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), so the function expects an object like this to be passed: `{ canvasID: "`…`", labels: [`…`], data: "`…`", noDataMessage: "`…`", symbols: [`…`] }`. It does *not* expect multiple parameters to be passed as individual values.

If no parameter is passed, the empty object `{}` with the given default values is used. Since the string `"cVacateDistribution"` has none of the properties `canvasID`, `labels`, `data`, `noDataMessage` or `symbols`, all of those are going to be their default values or `undefined`.

Comment: Turns out someone modified the ChartBuilder class and committed it without telling me, which broke my chart. Thank you very much for this!